# Transaction across WCF and REST

Tags: wcf, rest, transactions

We are having a business logic which involves call to services.
The application is built in c#.net and the business logic needs to make a call to the fallowing

1)Internal database call to update few fields

2)call to REST WCF service to store a document

3)call to web service to store data in queue

I want the above 3 steps to be Transactional.
Is there an approach these steps can be in transaction or is it something wrong with our approach?
Does anyone have experience in similer kind of requirement?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a number of questions.  Search for REST Transaction and you will find numerous answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST doesn't support transactions - if you want transactional support, you'll need to use the SOAP approach and the wsHttpBinding or the netTcpBinding.

Marc